# Select Case Sql

Tags: sql, case

Is this the correct way to use case to set variable values based on a field in a table?  It does not change when the field value changes from FMC to FSC to FSX.

```
           SET @coc_no =
            CASE
                --CHECK FOR FSC
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item AS i
                    WHERE i.Uf_Rex_Item_FSC_DESC = 'FMC')
                    THEN 'FSC Mix Credit SCS-COC-000000'
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item AS i
                    WHERE i.Uf_Rex_Item_FSC_DESC = 'FSC')
                    THEN 'FSC 100% SCS-COC-000000'
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item AS i
                    WHERE i.Uf_Rex_Item_FSC_DESC = 'FMX')
                    THEN 'FSC Mix(80%) SCS-COC-000000'
            END
```

Comment: A variable can only hold one value at a time.  It's unclear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `[item]` table contains some of each type of record, the result of this statement will **always** produce '`FSC Mix Credit SCS-COC-000000`'.

There is no concept anywhere in this code of looking at one current record. Every times this runs you're looking at the *entire table.* The `WHEN` expressions are evaluated in order, so it will look at the first expression, and if you have **any** `FMC` records anywhere in the table, that expression will evaluate to `true` and processing will stop.

Comment: Thanks.  Rethinking again.